# Get all values in current tag from multiple tags and inputs

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-pagination

I have a page where my tag in paginatethis is used to paginate all the fields. Now from my php script  2 to 100 paginatethis class=abc tags can be generated , How can I get the values of only the current field?  I have Used A Plugin For Pagination 
 [easyPagination](http://st3ph.github.io/jquery.easyPaginate/) hence im using the paginatethis tag

> My Pagination code looks like this

```
$('#qwe').easyPaginate({
    paginateElement: 'paginatethis.abc',
    elementsPerPage: 1,
    effect: 'climb'
});
```

This is my jQuery. I need to select all elements in the current paginatethis tag  on button click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".submit:current").click(function(){
        var quesid = $("#quesId").val();
        var oans = $("#oans").val();
        var cdate = $("#testDate").val();
        var studans = $("#answer:checked").val();

        $.ajax({  
            url: "<?php echo base_url('Front/submitAns');?>", 
            data: {
                quesid: quesid, 
                oans: oans, 
                cdate: cdate, 
                studans: studans
            },
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) { 
                $("#counts").html(data); 
            }    
        }); 
    });
});
```

```html
<paginatethis class="abc">
    <input type="radio" value="A" class="form-group" id="answer" name="answer">
    <input type="radio" value="B" class="form-group" id="answer" name="answer">
    <input type="radio" value="C" class="form-group" id="answer" name="answer">
    <input type="radio" value="D" class="form-group" id="answer" name="answer">
    <input type="hidden" name="testDate" value="<?php echo  date("Y-m-d");?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="oans" id="oans" value="<?php echo  base64_encode($data->ans);?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="quesId"  id="quesId" value="<?php echo  $data->id;?>" >
    <button type="button" name="submit" class="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</paginatethis>   <!--/value changed from above tag-->
<paginatethis class="abc"> 
    <input type="radio" value="A" class="form-group" id="answer" name="answer">
    <input type="radio" value="B" class="form-group" id="answer" name="answer">
    <input type="radio" value="C" class="form-group" id="answer" name="answer">
    <input type="radio" value="D" class="form-group" id="answer" name="answer">
    <input type="hidden" name="testDate" value="<?php echo  date("Y-m-d");?>" > //value changes in every tag
    <input type="hidden" name="oans" id="oans" value="<?php echo  base64_encode($data->ans);?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="quesId"  id="quesId" value="<?php echo  $data->id;?>" >    
    <button type="button" name="submit" class="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</paginatethis>
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle? Or at least a working version of `paginatethis`, as it's not a standard jquery lib (asaik).

Comment: i am using this plugin to do jquery pagination http://st3ph.github.io/jquery.easyPaginate/   so i can add my own tag and its working fine

Comment: Edit the post and add the fact that you use the lib easyPaginate. Also - it will be much easier to help if you provide a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) version.

Comment: whats i need is to grab the value from the current paginated page  every time the <paginatethis class="abc"> </paginatethis> occurs its is 1 page  and like this there could be 2-100 pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to get all the values of the inputs inside your current page.

Note that you will need to change the click event to handle clicks on DOM changes, so instead of `$('.select').click` I used `$('#qwe').on('click', '.submit',`

Here is an example:

```js
$('#qwe').easyPaginate({
  paginateElement: 'paginatethis.abc',
  elementsPerPage: 1,
  effect: 'climb'
});

$('#qwe').on('click', '.submit', function() {
  all_data_in_page = $('#qwe input').serialize();
  console.log(all_data_in_page);
  $.ajax({
    url: "your url",
    data: all_data_in_page,
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#counts").html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://st3ph.github.io/jquery.easyPaginate/js/jquery.easyPaginate.js"></script>
<div id="qwe">
  <paginatethis class="abc">
    Content of page 1
    <input type="radio" value="A" class="form-group" id="answer" name="answer">
    <input type="radio" value="B" class="form-group" id="answer" name="answer">
    <input type="radio" value="C" class="form-group" id="answer" name="answer">
    <input type="radio" value="D" class="form-group" id="answer" name="answer">
    <input type="hidden" name="testDate" value="1" >
    <input type="hidden" name="oans" id="oans" value="2" >
    <input type="hidden" name="quesId"  id="quesId" value="3" >
    <button type="button" name="submit" class="submit">SUBMIT</button>
  </paginatethis>
  <paginatethis class="abc"> 
    Content of page 2
    <input type="radio" value="A" class="form-group" id="answer" name="answer">
    <input type="radio" value="B" class="form-group" id="answer" name="answer">
    <input type="radio" value="C" class="form-group" id="answer" name="answer">
    <input type="radio" value="D" class="form-group" id="answer" name="answer">
    <input type="hidden" name="testDate" value="4" >
    <input type="hidden" name="oans" id="oans" value="5" >
    <input type="hidden" name="quesId"  id="quesId" value="6" >    
    <button type="button" name="submit" class="submit">SUBMIT</button>
  </paginatethis>
</div>
```

Comment: $('#qwe input').serialize(); assuming i want get only hidden fields and radio type     i would use?                                                                   ` $('#qwe input[type=hidden],#qwe input[type=rdio]').serialize();`   not at my pc right now left my laptop in the car but judging by the console output i guess it works then ill filter the data on server side

Comment: btw the comment above my thanks will that work for selecting the right inputs?

Comment: It should, however you better use `[type=radio]` (the `a` was missing there)

Comment: lol yea spelling error couldn't edit  after the next comment :P