# Jquery query string type to

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am using serialize()

```
Some Event trigger(assume click)

       var querydata= a=1&b=2&c=3  //jquery printing 
     $.ajax({
        url: "script",
        data: querydata,
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
          $("#counts").html(data);
            }

  });
```

in php do i just use the regular post method

```
a=htmlspecialchars($_POST["a"]); b=htmlspecialchars($_POST["b"]); and so on
```

or do i need to use jquery to get the string to variables and then send to data as a object array

if jquery is also an option could you tell me how i would do that im fairly new to jquery and i really want to learn it

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` would show you what php's receiving. and note that jquery will happily accept an array/object for `data` and do the necessary querystring transforms for you. you DON'T have to manually build the string yourself. `data: {"a":1,"b":2,....}` works just fine.

Comment: neat  but using ajax how do i see my script page ...im guessing i have to send var_dump as a response back and print it somewhere? @Marc B

Comment: any output from php would show up in the success handler's `data` parameter, which you're inserting into your page already anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother creating a functionality that your browser+PHP provide already??
In your case, if you really have to send a raw string:

```
var querydata = 'a=1&b=2&c=3';
$.ajax({
    url: "script",
    data: querydata,
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#counts").html(data);
    }
});
```

You may also want to simplify:

```
var querydata = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
$.post('url', querydata, function(data){
    $("#counts").html(data);
});
```

Comment: thing is the querydata variable will keep changing   there are 3(x150 pages) loaded everytimes a succesfull submit happens

Comment: and each time query data will  change so i dont think using  a built array would work form me  casue values  assigned to a b c will changed based on what the user selects

Comment: Of course native arrays will work. Just capture the user input value: `{ a: $(':input[name="inputName"]').val() }`

Comment: the pages are all paginated using easyPagination lib   so from 1 field set iv captured  the values using serialize() thats why im getting a querystiring

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743168/get-all-values-in-current-tag-from-multiple-tags-and-inputs/38745143?noredirect=1#comment64871663_38745143 Edited

Comment: the console outputs it like that i was working on that earleir